# For two lists, l1 and l2, how to check that for all e1 ∈ l1, ∃p(e1,e2) where e2 is some element in l2, efficiently in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, iterator, traversal

Ok, not sure if that was the best title, but I have two python lists. L1 and L2 which both have elements of type T and do not have the same length.

I have a function p(T,T) which is a predicate checking a property about two elements of type T.

I would like to check that for all elements e in L1, p(e,e') holds, where e' is SOME element in L2. so basically for each element in L1 I go over the second list, and check if the predicate holds for any of the elements. But I also want to check the same thing for the other list.

p(T,T) is symmetric. So if p(e,e') then p(e',e). I do not want to do the same thing twice because of that symmetry. I need to somehow record that if I see p(e,e') then I know p(e',e) and not have to check again for the second list.

What is the best way to do this in python? I thought about having another field for each element e1 in each list, telling us whether p(e1, e2) holds, where e2 is a member of the other list. But I think that requires copying both of those lists so I don't mutate them. Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: If you are willing to do some precomputation, as you suggest, you can always do the check in O(1) time for each element of L1.  Just create two more lists LL1 and LL2, so that LL1[i]==1 if and only if for the ith element e1 of LL1 there exists e1 in L2 such that p(e1,e2).  You can record the answer to the overall question (for all e1 in L1 exists... ) too

Comment: Ok, I edited my question with that code. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you meant, but if that's it, then it makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @Alejandro: That doesn't really *save* any work; the precomputation is `O(n**2)`, and it's not very reusable.

Comment: OP didn't say whether it needed to be rebuilt.  Perhaps they just want to query it a lot.

Comment: allocation of the 2d list in this way is not O(n**2), if that's the problem, and we only check up to the point we need then break the loop

Comment: Even if you are breaking early when you find something, worst case behaviour of that double loop is O(n**2).  In any case, I think I mislead you.  Can you clarify for us whether or not you want do this check frequently for the same pair of lists, or whether you are always building new lists L1 and L2 and needed to do the computation efficiently on the fly?

Comment: @Alejandro: If you want to do this check repeatedly for the same pair of lists, wouldn't you just precompute "yes" or "no" and return that every time?

Comment: Yep... so probably not what the OP is asking, eh :s

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `p` is symmetric is essentially useless. It's true that if you know `p(e, e')` holds, you know `p(e', e)` holds, but unless `e` and `e'` are both in both lists, you only get to make use of your predicate evaluation once instead of twice. Even if the lists are likely to have substantial overlap, it may still be more efficient to repeat `p` evaluations than to try to exploit symmetry.

The best way to perform the check you want is probably going to involve reorganizing your data and taking advantage of some further structure of `e` to find a more efficient algorithm, but with the information we have, we can't help you with that. The best I can suggest is brute force:

```
def check(p, l1, l2):
    for a in l1:
        if not any(p(a, b) for b in l2):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: How about `all(any(p(a,b) for b in l2) for a in l1)`?

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a dictionary for each list (could be `dict1` and `dict2`), and when you iterate through the first list, you set both `dict1[e] = e'` and `dict2[e'] = e`. Then, when iterating through `L2`, you just check first that the current `e` isn't in `dict2`. Could also add this check to the first iteration in `L1` if there are duplicate `e` values. Hope that makes sense - writing this on my phone.

Comment: "you set both `dict1[e] = e'` and `dict2[e'] = e`" - but you don't know what `e'` would have to be by looking at `e`, or vice versa. If you did, there would be much more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: I thought OP was just asking how to avoid checking again once he/she found e'

Comment: And because it is symmetric, e" is e